2D drag and drop dynamic rigid body spinning out of control in Unity
I'm trying to make a 2d game that involves dragging and dropping certain dynamic physics objects (like squares) and I am a beginner. I need it to look like the rest of the object holds a weight when you click on the object at a point. (like a ragdoll, but without any joints) This means that the object holds a center of mass that will kind of swing along the point on it you have clicked as a fulcrum.
So far I have made a rigid body object that can have its center follow my cursor and that holds a center of mass defined by another game object which only seemed to be effective when I let go of the object. I looked around on the web and I learned about the rigid body method AddForceAtPosition, which I used to keep the 'initial grab point' centered on my cursor as it dragged the rest of the object, with its center of mass around.
However, when I implement this it seems that the object spins and jumps out of control. When I was first making the object follow my cursor, I experienced a similar thing with force overshoot and just added a resistance term which is proportional to velocity and it made the dragging much smoother.
I used two scripts (one for dragging and one for setting the center of mass) on my parent game object (whose children are the sprite and the center of mass) in my attempt to achieve this. Any help with modifying my code or changing the approach would be awesome.
Drag Script (makes a force on an initial grab point follow cursor)
using UnityEngine;
public class ApplyContinuousForce : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float forceMag = 0.5f; // Force magnitude
    public float resistance = 2f;
    public float maxLaunchVelocity = 10f;

    private bool isDragging = false;
    private Vector2 force;
    private Camera mainCamera;
    private Vector3 initialClickOffset;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        if (rb == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No Rigidbody2D component found on this GameObject.");
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        isDragging = true;
        Vector3 mousePosition = GetMouseWorldPosition();
        initialClickOffset = transform.position - mousePosition;
        Debug.Log("Mouse Down - Start Dragging");
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        isDragging = false;
        rb.velocity = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(rb.velocity, maxLaunchVelocity);
        Debug.Log("Mouse Up - Stop Dragging. Clamped Velocity: " + rb.velocity);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            Vector3 currentMousePosition = GetMouseWorldPosition();
            Vector2 targetPosition = currentMousePosition + initialClickOffset;
            Vector2 offset = targetPosition - (Vector2)transform.position;

            // Calculate the force based on the mouse movement and apply resistance
            force = offset * forceMag - rb.velocity*resistance;

            // Apply the force continuously while dragging
            rb.AddForceAtPosition(force, currentMousePosition);
            Debug.Log("Dragging - Force: " + force+" Torque: "+rb.angularVelocity);
        }
    }

    private Vector3 GetMouseWorldPosition()
    {
        Vector3 mousePoint = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePoint.z = 10f; // Set this to the distance from the camera to the object
        return mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePoint);
    }
}

Change Center of Mass
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeCenterOfMass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform CenterOfMassReference; // The reference transform for the new center of mass
    private Vector2 centerOfMass;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        if (rb != null && CenterOfMassReference != null)
        {
            // Calculate the new center of mass in local space coordinates
            centerOfMass = transform.InverseTransformPoint(CenterOfMassReference.position);
            // Set the new center of mass
            rb.centerOfMass = centerOfMass;
        }
    }
}


You should do this with a joint instead of with forces.
(Edit: These steps are for 3D gameplay because I didn't read the question carefully enough. Oops!)
Create a Rigidbody (let's call it the "Hand" for the sake of example) and set it to be kinematic (meaning it is moved by script rather than with physics). Add the Character Joint component to this object (despite the confusing name, this is a generic ball-and-socket joint).
When the user clicks on a Rigidbody (let's call it the "Target") to start dragging it, move the "Hand" Rigidbody to the cursor position, and then set the connectedBody property of the Hand's Character Joint to connect to the Target.
When the user drags the cursor, the Hand should move with the cursor (you can move it with [MovePosition()] rather than by using forces) and the Target will automatically move with the Hand, while dangling from the Hand with physics. When the user releases the mouse button, disconnect the joint by setting the connectedBody property to null.
You may need to adjust the Character Joint settings to get it to look the way you want. Or, if you can't achieve what you want with Character Joint, you could try Configurable Joint instead, but be warned that Configurable Joint is very complex and may be difficult to understand.

I figured it out! Taking Kevin's advice about using joints instead of forces.
I couldn't find his referenced Character Joint component to work for 2D, but I did find something called a hinge joint which seemed to be exactly what I needed.
I made a hand game object and put it on a separate layer.
I added:

A box collider so it could take up some small space in order to be dragged
A default Hinge Joint 2D property
A rigid body 2D property with the gravityscale set to 0

Then, I made a 2d square sprite for my draggable object and gave it:

A box collider
A rigidbody 2d where I set the angular drag to ~6
My center of mass script
My HandControl Script

Hand Control Script:
using UnityEngine;

public class handcontrol : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D handRB;
    public HingeJoint2D handjoint;
    private Vector3 offset;
    private bool isDragging = false;
    private Camera mainCamera;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector3 lastMousePosition;
    private Vector3 currentMousePosition;
    private Vector3 launchVelocity;

    [SerializeField]
    private float maxLaunchVelocity = 10f; // Maximum allowed launch velocity

    void Start()
    {
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        handRB.position = GetMouseWorldPosition();
        handjoint.connectedBody = rb;
        handRB.velocity = Vector2.zero; // Stop any existing movement
        isDragging = true;
        offset = handRB.position - (Vector2)GetMouseWorldPosition();
        lastMousePosition = GetMouseWorldPosition();
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        handjoint.connectedBody = null;
        isDragging = false;
        handRB.velocity = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(launchVelocity, maxLaunchVelocity); // Apply the capped launch velocity
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            currentMousePosition = GetMouseWorldPosition();
            handRB.MovePosition(currentMousePosition + offset);
            launchVelocity = (currentMousePosition - lastMousePosition) / Time.deltaTime;
            lastMousePosition = currentMousePosition;
        }
    }

    private Vector3 GetMouseWorldPosition()
    {
        Vector3 mousePoint = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePoint.z = 10f; // Set this to the distance from the camera to the object
        return mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePoint);
    }
}

The script is basically a primitive drag script which when the LMB is held on the square (object being dragged)

the hand gets continually teleported to the cursor
the square gets used as the hand's hinge joint connected body
updates a velocity vector based on the previous and current mouse position

so that when the mouse releases:

the square gets removed from the hand's hinge joint
a conservation of momentum gets held (you can throw the square)

To use the script, make sure to select your hand object as a public variable in the property inspector for the square (dragging object)

Whoops, I was tired yesterday and I guess I missed that your question was about 2D gameplay. Sorry about that! I'm glad you were able to figure out the solution from there.

no worries! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction
